# How to make an anonymous types property name dynamic?

Tags: c#, linq, anonymous-types

I have a following LinqToXml query:

```
  var linqDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
  var result = linqDoc.Descendants()
    .GroupBy(elem => elem.Name)
    .Select(group => new 
    { 
      TagName = group.Key.ToString(), 
      Values = group.Attributes("Id")
        .Select(attr => attr.Value).ToList() 
    });
```

Is it possible somehow to make the field of my anonymous type it to be the variable value, so that it could be as (not working):

```
  var linqDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
  var result = linqDoc.Descendants()
   .GroupBy(elem => elem.Name)
   .Select(group => new 
   { 
     group.Key.ToString() = group.Attributes("Id")
       .Select(attr => attr.Value).ToList() 
   });
```

Comment: You want to dinamically name the type's fields? Say `a` is an instance of that anonymous type. How do you get the value of that field now, if you don't know its name?

Comment: No*. Even if it would be possible, how would you access the field?

Comment: Consider using a `Dictionary` instead; it's easy to create with the `ToDictionary`-method.

Comment: You could use ExpandoObject instead of anonymous class?

Comment: @sloth Maybe it could have some synonym like "group.Key.ToString() as Field1" or something like that. So I could access this field by the synonim

Comment: @DavidG The names of the fields of an `ExpandoObject` must also be known at compile-time. Unless you cast it to a dictionary first, but then you're better off just using *a* dictionary.

Comment: @voo If you're going to give it a compile time name, then what's the point of a dynamic name?

Comment: @Servy I need it to serialize to json next

Comment: @voo Then you have an XY problem.  Ask how to serialize this data, which doesn't have a static schema at compile time, to JSON.  The appropriate way to do so almost certainly won't involve an anonymous type.

Comment: @servy Well, don't know for sure, but I would create some alias-value mapping table for my anonymous object and use it in the serializer

Comment: @voo And I'm telling you that that's not the appropriate way to serialize this data.  You should ask how to serialize this data, not how to create an anonymous type with dynamic fields, and you will be given the *appropriate* way of serializing this data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, even anonymous types must have compile-time field names.  It seems like to want a collection of different types, each with different field names.  Maybe you could use a `Dictionary` instead?

```
  var result = linqDoc.Descendants()
                      .GroupBy(elem => elem.Name)
                      .ToDictionary(
                                    g => g.Key.ToString(), 
                                    g => g.Attributes("Id").Select(attr => attr.Value).ToList()
                                   );
```

Note that Dictionaries can be serialized to JSON easily:

```
{ 
  "key1": "type1":
            {
              "prop1a":"value1a",
              "prop1b":"value1b"
            }, 
  "key2": "type2":
            {
              "prop2a":"value2a",
              "prop2b":"value2b"
            }
}
```